# How to fill in every nth row with values from another column with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi supposed I have a dataframe as such

```
temp <- data.frame(value = sample(c ( 1:312), 20 ), value2 = sample(c ( 1:312), 20 )  )

   value value2
1    217    270
2    299    155
3     77    249
4    116     89
5     54     18
6    248    228
7    154    273
8    218    146
9    149    131
10   134     68
11   282     47
12   169    196
13    20    276
14   233    240
15   222     92
16   102      1
17   297     49
18     9     65
19   289    118
20    75    255
```

What I like to do is  fill in every 3rd row with the data from value2. So for example, all rows above rows 1 & 2 would be 0 and the third row would 249, rows 5 &6 are 0 and row 7 would be 273 and so fourth.

Would be great if I can do with dplyr. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `if_else` -

```
set.seed(123)
temp <- data.frame(value = sample(c(1:312), 20), value2 = sample(c(1:312), 20))

temp %>%
  mutate(value3 = if_else(row_number() %% 3 == 0, value2, 0L))

#   value value2 value3
#1    179    211      0
#2     14     78      0
#3    195     81     81
#4    306     43      0
#5    118    143      0
#6    299     32     32
#7    229    109      0
#8    244    263      0
#9    311     23     23
#10   153    135      0
#11    90    224      0
#12    91    166    166
#13   256    217      0
#14   197    290      0
#15   301     69     69
#16   137     72      0
#17    26     76      0
#18     7     63     63
#19   297    141      0
#20   254    210      0
```

Comment: thanks, however I encounter an error when one of the values is a decimal. for example. `temp[3, ]$value2 = 6.78` gives this error `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector.

Comment: You may remove `L` from `0L` or another option is to use `ifelse` instead of `if_else`.

Comment: inerestingly when I replaced 0L with just 0 it seem to work.

Comment: Thanks. It works. What is  0L by the way?

Comment: `L` is used to specify integer values. `if_else` is type strict hence, you get the error because `value2` is numeric whereas `0L` is integer. Check `class(0L)` and `class(0)`.

Comment: ah I see, thanks, learning a lot from you this evening, cheers mate.